# Magento - Products not showing on "not visible individually"

Tags: php, magento

I've got a website with Magento Enterprise Edition's 1.14.1.0.

If I set my product's visibility to "not visible individually" it will return **404 error** when I try to access their details page directly using url.

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: well that is the behaviour of "not visible individually" you cannot view their product page individually...

Comment: This is the default feature. Mostly this option is used for configurable product and bundle product but not simple product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento has functionality to make certain items not visible individually so you can, for example, take 6 products and turn it into 1 product where a customer can choose their options.
You then hide all the individual products, leaving only that one product visible on the site and reducing duplicate content issues.

So those individual pages never actually appear on the site. They are just created to allow Magento to pull inventory on those items from that configurable product.

I would get a 404 (and if I searched for it, nothing would come up) because as far as the world outside of Magento admin is concerned, that URL doesn't exist.